# Force Glide to look at the signature only to cache or redownload, so ignore different URI (Android)

Tags: android, android-glide

My backend changes the url to the same picture everytime I request it, which causes Glide to redownload the picture even if it did not change.
So I was wondering if it is possible to let Glide ignore looking at the changing url and only check at the signature so it can cache for my application properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/607

You need to override the getCacheKey() method like this:

```
public class GlideUrlWithToken extends GlideUrl {
        private String mSourceUrl;

        public GlideUrlWithToken(String url, String token) {
            super(new StringBuilder(url)
                    .append(token) // append the token at the end of url
                    .toString());

            Preconditions.checkNotNull(url);
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(token);

            mSourceUrl = url;
            Log.v(TAG, url);
        }

        @Override
        public String getCacheKey() {
            return mSourceUrl;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.getCacheKey();
        }
    }
```

Then you can call Glide like the following:

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(new GlideUrlWithToken(image.getLink(), token))
                    .signature(new StringSignature(signature))
                    .into(imageView);
```

Signature here holds my imageId + the updatedAt value from the server, so it should redownload the image if it gets updated.